# POST from partial view is hitting controller twice

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form in a view (Edit view), and a partial view inside that form on the Edit view.  The partial view has its own form which performs a lookup. The lookup in the partial view is successfully returning the results to the Edit view. However, the POST from the partial view is then hitting the controller a second time (trying to submit the form in the Edit view).  How do I stop the POST from hitting the controller a second time?

Here is where the partial view is called in the Edit view:

```
<div class="form-group" id="search-pac">
    @Html.Action("PacSearch", "ItemRequest");
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="search-pac-results">
</div>
```

Here is where the controller gets the partial view:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult PacSearch()
{
    return PartialView("_PacSearchFormPartial");
}
```

Here is the form in the partial view:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("PacSearch", "ItemRequest", FormMethod.Post,
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        UpdateTargetId = "search-pac-results"
    }))
{
    <div>
        @Html.TextBox("pacupc")
        <input type="submit" value="Find PAC" />
    </div>      
}
```

Which then hits the controller here:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PacSearch(string pacupc)
{  
    //do lookup stuff, and call a partial view to display the results
}
```

Once the results are displayed on the Edit view, POST then hits the controller here (which I don't want unless the submit button in the Edit view is clicked):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ItemRequest itemRequest, HttpPostedFileBase upcImage, Comment comment, String FinalApproval)
{  
    //handle form submission from Edit View
}
```

How do I keep the POST from the partial view from hitting the HttpPost for Edit view in the controller?

**UPDATE:**
Upon the suggestion to use a direct AJAX call, I ditched the partial views and changed my Edit view to:

```
                            <div class="form-group" id="search-pac">
                                @Html.TextBox("pacupc")
                                <input type="button" id="btn-pacupc" value="Find PAC" />
                              @*  @Html.Action("PacSearch", "ItemRequest");*@
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group" id="search-pac-results">
                            </div>
```

And AJAX call:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on('click', '#btn-pacupc', function () {
                var pacupc = $("#pacupc").val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "@Url.Action("PacSearch")",
                    data: { pacupc: pacupc },
                    success: function (result) { $('#search-pac-results').html(result); }
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Is the partial view call wrapped in the call to the edit action?

Comment: @Robert:  Ah, yes, it is.  In my edit view, I first have: "@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "ItemRequest", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))" and then inside that, I have the partial view.  The lookup from the partial view appears in the middle of my edit form, which is where I need it to display.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no support for forms within forms in HTML. A submission inside the innermost form will also submit any parent form. The solution then, is to not rely on `Ajax.BeginForm`, which will print a form element to the page, and instead, wire your AJAX manually. This is a prime example of why I encourage everyone to not use the `Ajax` family of helpers. They simply do *too* much, hidden to the developer, and often lead to confusion when things don't work as expected, which happens far more often than not.

Comment: You could also try to prevent the event from bubbling to the outer form by handlers to BeginForm event, but I have often found the same as you.  It's easier to implement a simple click handler, $.ajax submit, and .done(... someElement.html(result))

Comment: I was a Python developer before I started working with C# and .NET. There's a mantra in PEP 20 (http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) that every Python developer worth his salt eats, sleeps and breathes. Part of that is "explicit is better than implicit", which is why I think `Ajax.*` bugs me so much -- way too much implicitness there.

Comment: can you give me an example of how to write the AJAX call?

Comment: nevermind.  I figured out the call. I will edit my post with how I changed it.